# Specifying an object type in typescript, converting from JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add particles to the background of a React website written in typescript (.tsx) and am using this particle-bg component: https://github.com/lindelof/particles-bg

I need to insert this code into my .tsx file but am getting an error `Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I imagine this is because it is javascript and not properly specifying the object type.  How would convert this to typescript?

```
let config = {
      num: [4, 7],
      rps: 0.1,
      radius: [5, 40],
      life: [1.5, 3],
      v: [2, 3],
      tha: [-40, 40],
      // body: "./img/icon.png", // Whether to render pictures
      // rotate: [0, 20],
      alpha: [0.6, 0],
      scale: [1, 0.1],
      position: "center", // all or center or {x:1,y:1,width:100,height:100}
      color: ["random", "#ff0000"],
      cross: "dead", // cross or bround
      random: 15,  // or null,
      g: 5,    // gravity
      // f: [2, -1], // force
      onParticleUpdate: (ctx, particle) => {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(particle.p.x, particle.p.y, particle.radius * 2, particle.radius * 2);
          ctx.fillStyle = particle.color;
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.closePath();
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <SignIn />
        <ParticlesBg type="custom" config={config} bg={true} />
      </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change to this:

```
onParticleUpdate: (ctx: any, particle: any)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of particles-bg, at src/index.d.ts, you'll see

```
export interface ConfigProp {
    num: number[];
    rps: number;
    radius: number[];
    life: number[];
    v: number[];
    tha: number[];
    body?: string;
    rotate?: number[];
    alpha: number[];
    scale: number[];
    position: ConfigPositionProp;
    color: string[];
    cross: string;
    random: number | null;
    g: number;
    f?: number[];
    onParticleUpdate?: (ctx: any, particle: any) => void;
  }
```

That's the type the component is expecting for the config prop.
You can import that type and then write this:

```
const config: ConfigProp = {
```

And your config object will be typed correctly.